# Switch Case always goes to default

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

I am trying to make a small operating system that takes a response from a switch...case to go to a miniature game or a simple calculator. However, no matter what input I give (even correct ones) the output is always the default. 
The compiler I am using (Microsoft Visual Studio; It could be the problem) isn't giving me any errors, and I can't find or think of any mistakes. Do some of you people who are actually good at this have any answers to my problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int calc() {

char op;
float num1, num2;

cout << "Enter operation:";
cin >> op;

cout << "Enter two numbers:";
cin >> num1 >> num2;

switch (op)
{
case '+':
    cout << num1 + num2;
    break;

case '-':
    cout << num1 - num2;
    break;

case '*':
    cout << num1 * num2;
    break;

case '/':
    cout << num1 / num2;
    break;

default:
    cout << "That is not an operation";
    break;
}

return 0;
};

int main()
{
char answer;

cout << "Welcome to the FR Operating System. \n";
cout << "If you want to go to the calculator, type in 'Calc'. \n";
cout << "If you want to go to the game, type in 'Game'. \n";

cin >> answer;

switch (answer) {
case 'Calc' || 'calc':
    cout << "Welcome to the calculator. \n";
    break;

case 'Game':
    cout << "Welcome to our game, 'A Day in the Life'. \n";
    break;

default:
    cout << "That is an invalid answer. This has caused the system to crash. \n";
    break;
}

atexit([] { system("PAUSE"); });

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `case 'Calc' || 'calc':` is not a valid `case` statement. You need separate `case` statements for each value you want to compare. But you can't use strings with `case` statements.  `'Calc'`, `'calc'`, `'Game'`, these are not treated as strings, they are treated as multi-byte characters instead since you are using single-quotes instead of double-quotes

Comment: Out of curiosity: are serious with developing an OS? It would be new to me that Visual Studio can compile one :D I think you rather mean console application instead of operating system? :)

Comment: @sebrockm I'm just making a small one to help me learn.

Comment: @McOcelot Well, I see that it is small :) But are you really talking about a real OS with boot sector and so forth? I've never touched that topic that's why I am asking

Answer (score 3):

1. `'Game'` is not a valid string
2. Even if you replace it by `"Game"`, which is a valid string, `switch` doesn't work with strings.

So either use single chars in your switch or use `if`-`else` blocks where you compare `std::string`s via `==`.

```
std::string answer;
cin >> answer;
if (answer == "Calc" || answer == "calc")
    //...
else if (answer == "Game")
    //...
else
    // invalid
```

Comment: This is more apt solution rather using switch case. +1.

Answer (score 2):

### Use map to item callbacks

Ideally, it would be better to map item menu to it's respective actions. `std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>>` allows exactly that! Read the inline comments to make sense of the rest:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> menu_items;
    menu_items.emplace("calc", [](){std::cout << "calculate chosen\n";}); //use lambdas to spare boilerplate
    menu_items.emplace("game", [](){std::cout << "game is chosen\n";});

    std::string chosen_item;
    std::cin >> chosen_item;
    auto item = menu_items.find(chosen_item); //search by the string
    if (item == menu_items.end()) //item was not found in the list
        std::cout << "invalid item is chosen\n";
    else
        item->second(); //execute the stored function
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zklEb5kPMGOgHGYj).

Depending on your usage you might want to use `void*()` for `std::function<void()>`, and `std::unordered_map` for `std::map`. For your usage case it doesn't seem to matter though.

Also you might want to normalize the input, e.g. lowercase the string, or perform some other normalization. Since this is not performance sensitive part of the code, I believe overhead of `std::function` and `std::map` won't matter in this case.

Comment: If I understood correctly, OP wants to handle these two **'Calc' || 'calc'** situations correctly or same. How would your code handle this key `"calc"`? I am also wondering, whether we really need to choose `std::map` for a simple `switch` case problem.

Comment: @JeJo, one can just run std::tolower to normalize the string. If it goes really bad, one can also map multiple strings to the same lambda. I just couldn't craft any switch version that would be as ergonomic as `std::map`.

Comment: I have already explained the reason. Considering the fact that it works as an alternative I have reversed it.

Comment: I like this solution. One issue: it is not flexible if you want to process some strings casesensitive and others not

Comment: @JeJo, Looking at the other answer I understand your point better. I believe map scales better as the menu could be written in a text file, parsed, then returned as map. I guess I over-engineered it

Comment: @sebrockm, I believe the problem boils down to normalization+enumeration, which is just collection of ifs :)

Comment: @Incomputable true, and once you have that collection of ifs the map becomes kind of redundant :)

Comment: @sebrockm, separation of concerns is a thing for me. If enumeration is done, I would replace with a array to void functions, which would compile into nice jump table. Anyway, have a nice morning/day/evening. Gotta go to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You are prompting user for a `string` while your variable `answer` is a `char`, change your prompts to characters like `c` and `g` thus make it more convenient,  thus you can use and enumerate characters in your `switch` / `case` statement:

```
int main()
{
char answer;

cout << "Welcome to the FR Operating System. \n";
cout << "If you want to go to the calculator, type in 'c'. \n";
cout << "If you want to go to the game, type in 'g'. \n";
cin >> answer;
switch (answer) {
case 'c':
case 'C':
    cout << "Welcome to the calculator. \n";
    break;

case 'g':
case 'G':
    cout << "Welcome to our game, 'A Day in the Life'. \n";
    break;
...
```